# How to connect remotely to sql database in docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

newbie here.
I have a docker container with a mysql server on it. I want to be able to work on it on different pc.

Following a guide I did these steps:

1)create a db and an account with all privileges

2)got the machine ip throudh powershell with:
"docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME"

3)tried to connect to my server in workbench

It didn't work but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Anybody can give me a step by step guide to follow? Thank you

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is essentially useless: it's unreachable from other hosts, and it's unreachable even from the same host on Windows systems.  On native Linux you'd be able to reach the container via the first `docker run -p` port number and the host's DNS name or IP address, but this may not work on Windows.

Comment: Ty, I thought I had to use my public IP but it was the local one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add port mapping using `docker run -p` and modify inbound firewall rules in the PC where container is running to allow traffic on the port from another machine in same network

Comment: Ty, It seems it worked. I thought I had to use my public IP but it was the local one. There's no way to connect to the database outside of the network?